# Filtering by two different categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, filtering

I have a list of people and their activities.

I would like to have them filtered by two categories, **NAME** and **ACTIVITY**. 
I made two select's and filled one with people's names and one with their activities.

```
<select class="filter people">
<option value="0">ALL PEOPLE</option
<option value="1">John</option>
<option value="2">Mary</option>
<option value="3">Dan</option>
etc.
</select>

<select class="filter activities">
<option value="0">ALL ACTIVITIES</option
<option value="1">Football</option>
<option value="2">Basketball</option>
<option value="3">Painting</option>
<option value="4">Racing</option>
etc.
</select>
```

Sample of list structure.

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="item people3 activity2">Dan:Basketball</div>
<div class="item people3 activity1">Dan:Football</div>
<div class="item people1 activity2">John:Basketball</div>
</div>
```

What i want is to show all items which include selected filter.

For example, selecting only *BASKETBALL* under category dropdown, it would hide every item except `Dan:Basketball` and `John:Basketball`, selecting *BASKETBALL* under category, and *JOHN* under people, it would hide every item except `John:Basketball`. Item with value **0**, shows **all** items from selected filter.

Here is what i tried so far. It works only with one filter, now i would like to combine it to work with `(n)` filters, in my case two, people and activities.

```
// $('.filter').change(function(){

$('.people').change(function(){

if($(this).val()!=0) {

if(current != '') {

$('div.item').not('.'+current).show();

}

current = $(this).val();

$('div.item').not('.'+current).hide();

} else $('.item').show();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not creating a seperate function to apply the filtering?

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npL4xc6m/)

```
$('.people').change(function(){
    applyFilter();
});

$('.activities').change(function(){
    applyFilter();
});

function applyFilter() {
    // get selected people and activity
    var people = $('.people').val();
    var activity = $('.activities').val();

    // add people and activity to filter array
    var classFilter = [];
    if (people !=0) {
        classFilter.push('people'+people);
    }
    if (activity != 0) {
        classFilter.push('activity' + activity);
    }

    // show all if filter array empty or apply filter
    if (classFilter.length == 0) {
        $("div.item").show();
    } else {
        $("div.item").hide();
        $("div.item." + classFilter.join(".")).show();
    }
 }
```

You can make it more generic yourself from here to support additional filtering.

Comment: Works great! I like the option to add additional n-number of select filters. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully generic solution ;)

```
$('select.filter').on('change', function(){

  var class = '';

  $('select.filter').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != 0)
       class += '.' + $(this).attr('class').replace('filter ', '') + $(this).val();
  });

  $('.item').show();
  $('.item').not(class).hide();

});
```

Comment: Tried in JSfiddle, but it unfortunately it doesnt work. I like your solution because it is short and simple. Try editing it and i will give you an upvote! :)